# Comparing year from st_mtime in c

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing my own ls -l program and I have to display file midification date. It worked just fine to the point i realised that is should show date in format 'dd' 'mm' and then hour and minute just for files from present year.
If something I'm checking is a directory or was modified last in different year
I'd have to output the date in format of 'dd' 'mm' 'yyyy'.
I don't know how to compare only year from st_mdate to change the output.
Tried making if statement with checking if something i'm describing is a directory, it worked. But now I need to do something similar for normal files too.
And my question is how to compare st_mdate years to do that.

Here's my function:

```
void mdate(struct stat mystat){
    if(S_ISDIR(mystat.st_mode)){
        char mtime[80];
        time_t t = mystat.st_mtime;  
        struct tm lt;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt); 
        strftime(mtime, sizeof mtime, "%d %b %Y ", &lt);
        printf(" %-12s", strtok(mtime,"n"));
    }
    else{
        char mtime[80];
        time_t t = mystat.st_mtime;
        struct tm lt;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt); 
        strftime(mtime, sizeof mtime, "%d %b %H:%M ", &lt);
        printf(" %-12s", strtok(mtime,"n"));
    }       
}
```

**Edit:**
Here's my 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOfI1.png)

**Edit 2**

Got it, here's my final code:

```
void mdate(struct stat mystat){
    time_t current;
    time_t t = mystat.st_mtime;  
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char mtime[80];
    struct tm lt;

    time ( &current );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &current );
    localtime_r(&t, &lt); 

    if(S_ISDIR(mystat.st_mode)|| (timeinfo->tm_year>lt.tm_year)) {
        strftime(mtime, sizeof mtime, "%d %b %Y ", &lt);
        printf(" %-13s", strtok(mtime,"\n"));
    }
    else {
        strftime(mtime, sizeof mtime, "%d %b %H:%M ", &lt);
        printf(" %-13s", strtok(mtime,"\n"));
    }       
}
```

Comment: Look at `lt.tm_year` to see if the year has changed — I'm not sure if you'd be comparing with the `tm_year` based on the current time, but you'll find the correct comparison.  Beware: `tm_year` has 1900 subtracted from it.

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, post it below as an _answer_.

Comment: Posting text as text rather than as a picture is more useful.  Your output picture does not match the question's code, so best to post code and matching true output.